# Why does my JS object end up having "undefined" values?

Tags: javascript

```
var testRuleInput = {
    "ruleName" : "renderDataVerificationFields",
    "dependencies" : [
        {
            "fieldName" : "mailingStreetAddress",
            "resource" : "verificationResults",
            "attribute" : "verifyStreetAddress"
        }
    ]
};
```

However, when I later call `console.log(testRuleInput.dependencies.attribute)`; I get `undefined`. Confused!

Comment: dependencies is an array. Use: `console.log(testRuleInput.dependencies[0].attribute)`

Comment: or, if you don't intend to have more than one object in dependencies, get rid of the array notation `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependencies` is an array of objects.

Update your code with:

```
console.log(testRuleInput.dependencies[0].attribute)
```

Or drop the array syntax:

```
"dependencies": {
    "fieldName": "mailingStreetAddress",
    "resource": "verificationResults",
    "attribute": "verifyStreetAddress"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `dependencies` is an array. I think you're looking for `testRuleInput.dependencies[0].attribute`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array.

```
testRuleInput.dependencies[0].attribute
```

Remove the square brackets if you only want 1 dependency or index it properly like the above.

```
var testRuleInput = {
                        "ruleName" : "renderDataVerificationFields",
                        "dependencies" : {
                            "fieldName" : "mailingStreetAddress",
                            "resource" : "verificationResults",
                            "attribute" : "verifyStreetAddress"
                        }
                   };
```

Answer (score 0):

`testRuleInput.dependencies` is an array. If you use `testRuleInput.dependencies[0].attribute` you'll get what you're expecting.